# Check if date range is sequential in c#?

Tags: c#, .net-2.0

Assume I have a user interface where the user can select days.  Is there a way to check if the days selected are sequential, such as:

4/4, 4/5, 4/6, 4/7, 4/8, 4/9, 4/10 or

4/29, 4/30, 5/1, 5/2, 5/3

I know I probably can loop through the date range and check, but I was more curious if there was a built in method already to check for this.

Regarding the above scenarios, they are in order and they can roll over into the next month.

I am using the .NET Framework 2.0 and can't use LINQ.

Regarding Tom's answer:

```
DateTime dtStart = new DateTime(2011,5,4);
DateTime dtEnd = new DateTime(2011,5,11);

int numberOfDaysSelected = 7; //Assume 7 days were selected.

TimeSpan ts = dtEnd - dtStart;


if(ts.Days == numberOfDaysSelected - 1)
{
Console.WriteLine("Sequential");
}
else
{
Console.WriteLine("Non-Sequential");
}
```

Comment: should be `if(ts.Days == numberOfDaysSelected-1)`, since for two consecutive days you have a time span of one day, not two.

Comment: If the start date is 5/4/2011 and the end date is 5/11/2011, that is actually 8 days total that were selected (5/4, 5/5, 5/6, 5/7, 5/8, 5/9, 5/10, and 5/11). You need to take into consideration BrokenGlass' fix mentioned in the comment above. I will edit my answer to reflect the "-1" required.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I do not believe there is a built in method to achieve your desired results but if you can easily tell the earliest and latest dates, you could create a new TimeSpan by subtracting the the earliest date from the latest date and then verifying that the number of days of the timespan matches the number of dates selected - 1.

Comment: +1 unless i'm missing something this is a good solution to the problem

Comment: +1, because I believe that this is the neatest solution. Note, however, that it requires that there are no duplicates in your date list.

Comment: This is a neat solution, and it is impossible for their to be duplicates.

Comment: -1 because it makes the assumption that the list of dates dates are both unique and ordered.

Comment: @Nicholas, but getting an ordered, unique list is a trivial operation. `var shinyList = origList.OrderBy(d => d.Day).Distinct();`

Comment: @Nicholas, the question states they are ordered. I did leave out the assumption that they are unique which was an assumption I made myself when reading the question. The dates don't need to be ordered though, my solution specifically states "if you can easily tell the earliest and latest dates." The order does not matter.

Comment: @Tom, I will update my post with a code sample of what I think you meant. Let me know if it is correct?

Answer (score 2):

You didn't tell us if the days are ordered.

You didn't tell us if they might fall over a month boundary as in

```
30, 31, 1.
```

I'll assume ordered, and I'll assume they won't fall over a month boundary (because your example is ordered, and it doesn't fall over a month boundary).

Then you can say

```
public bool IsSequential(this IEnumerable<DateTime> sequence) {
    Contract.Requires(sequence != null);
    var e = sequence.GetEnumerator();
    if(!e.MoveNext()) {
        // empty sequence is sequential
        return true;
    }
    int previous = e.Current.Date;
    while(e.MoveNext()) {
        if(e.Current.Date != previous.AddDays(1)) {
            return false;
        }      
        previous = e.Current.Date;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Note that this solution requires only walking the sequence once. If you don't have an ordered sequence, or if you permit falling over a month boundary the solution is more complicated.

Comment: Updated Post.  They are in order and they can roll over.  I updated the post with 2 scenarios.

Comment: @Xaisoft: Are they input as instances of `DateTime`?

Comment: -1, because implementing this with `int` rather than `DateTime` abuses the framework and imposes unnecessary constraints. I think that Tom has a better answer.

Comment: @Jason, yes they are DateTime instances.  In your code, what is Contract.Requires?

Comment: @JSBangs, does it matter in this case, will you ever find a day that is not an int.

Comment: @Xaisoft, dates are not ints. The day of the month is an int, as is the day of the year, but any scenario that requires you to span different months or different years will break or run into horrible special-cased code if you naively try to represent dates as ints. But the `DateTime` class already has this implemented for you, so why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: @JSBangs, I agree and do not want to reinvent the wheel, that is why the first thought that came to my mind was to use the TimeSpan as Tom mentioned.

Comment: @Xaisoft: `Contract.Requires` is a contract element from Code Contracts, [a language-agnostic way to express coding assumptions in .NET programs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/dd491992.aspx).

Comment: @JSBangs: The question has been edited. Note that the first comment on this very answer even states the post was updated. The initial example input was integers only. Don't penalize answerers for poorly written questions.

Comment: The question was not poorly written.  I said days, not integers.

Comment: @Xaisoft: Your example showed integers, and you didn't state explicitly that they were ordered nor that you could roll over a month boundary. A well written question does not require clarifications.

Comment: I apologize if it was poorly written.  When I said Days an put integers as the first example, I thought the integers would imply days of the week.  I also thought sequential would imply order with no gaps.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing built in but you can build one easily using Linq:

```
List<DateTime> timeList = new List<DateTime>();
//populate list..
bool isSequential = timeList.Zip(timeList.Skip(1), 
                                 (a, b) => b.Date == a.Date.AddDays(1))
                            .All(x => x);
```

Edited - misunderstood question first to mean ascending in time as opposed to sequential - fixed that.

Comment: One problem: I am still using .NET 2.0 and can't use LINQ.

Comment: @Xaisoft: Then ignore this solution, it only applies to .NET 4 - @Tom's approach should work.

Answer (score 1):

Extension method using Linq:

```
public static bool IsContiguous(this IEnumerable<DateTime> dates)
{
    var startDate = dates.FirstOrDefault();

    if (startDate == null)
        return true;

    //.All() doesn't provide an indexed overload :(
    return dates
        .Select((d, i) => new { Date = d, Index = i })
        .All(d => (d.Date - startDate).Days == d.Index);
}
```

Testing it:

```
List<DateTime> contiguousDates = new List<DateTime>
{
    new DateTime(2011, 05, 05),
    new DateTime(2011, 05, 06),
    new DateTime(2011, 05, 07),
};
List<DateTime> randomDates = new List<DateTime>
{
    new DateTime(2011, 05, 05),
    new DateTime(2011, 05, 07),
    new DateTime(2011, 05, 08),
};

Console.WriteLine(contiguousDates.IsContiguous());
Console.WriteLine(randomDates.IsContiguous());
```

Returns

```
True
False
```

**EDIT**:

.NET 2-like answer:

```
public static bool CheckContiguousDates(DateTime[] dates)
{
    //assuming not null and count > 0
    var startDate = dates[0];

    for (int i = 0; i < dates.Length; i++)
    {
        if ((dates[i] - startDate).Days != i)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Still on .NET 2 and can't use LINQ.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **TimeGapCalculator** of the [Time Period Library for .NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/168662/Time-Period-Library-for-NET) to find gaps between multiple time periods (independent of order, count and overlapping):

```
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------
public void SequentialPeriodsDemo()
{
  // sequential
  ITimePeriodCollection periods = new TimePeriodCollection();
  periods.Add( new Days( new DateTime( 2011, 5, 4 ), 2 ) );
  periods.Add( new Days( new DateTime( 2011, 5, 6 ), 3 ) );
  Console.WriteLine( "Sequential: " + IsSequential( periods ) );

  periods.Add( new Days( new DateTime( 2011, 5, 10 ), 1 ) );
  Console.WriteLine( "Sequential: " + IsSequential( periods ) );
} // SequentialPeriodsDemo

// --------------------------------------------------------------------
public bool IsSequential( ITimePeriodCollection periods, ITimePeriod limits = null )
{
  return new TimeGapCalculator<TimeRange>( 
    new TimeCalendar() ).GetGaps( periods, limits ).Count == 0;
} // IsSequential
```