# multiple date range and check if it is sequential. c# MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net

We have this project and one of the business requirement is it allows the client to input a multiple date range and check the individual dates if it is sequential/continuous or not to the others.

eq.

**INPUT**

startdate - enddate

10/24/2016 - 10/24/2016

10/26/2016 - 10/28/2016

**OUTPUT**

10/24/2016 - 10/24/2016 - NOT SEQUENTIAL

10/26/2016 - 10/26/2016 - SEQUENTIAL

10/27/2016 - 10/27/2016 - SEQUENTIAL

10/28/2016 - 10/28/2016 - SEQUENTIAL

For now I am playing around this solution 
[Check if date range is sequential in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5887079/check-if-date-range-is-sequential-in-c)
but i hope we i can find a better solution on how to properly do it.

Thank you and have a good day!

Comment: By "sequential" you mean that the second date is after the first?  DateTime.Compare(date1, date2) can do this for you.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.compare(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @nurdyguy sorry i have edited my post. if the 1st input was 10/25/2016 - 10/25/2016  then it was sequential to the 10/26/2016

Comment: So by "sequential" you mean the second one is on the day after, as in consecutive days?

Answer (score 1):

If by "sequential" we mean that the second date is the day after the first date then we can do the following:

```
private bool CheckSequential(DateTime date1, DateTime date2)
{
    // strips off time portion
    var d1 = date1.Date;
    var d2 = date2.Date;

    // add 1 to first date
    d1 = d1.AddDays(1);

    // compare them
    if(DateTime.Compare(d1, d2) == 0)
       return true;
    else
       return false;
}
```