# Return first sequential date block

Tags: c#, .net

I am looking to build on an already-answered solution around checking if a block of dates is sequential and it would then return a true/false bool value. The solution I have found that works well to do this is found here and the use of LINQ works well to determine the true/false. 
[Check if date range is sequential in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5887079/check-if-date-range-is-sequential-in-c). For reference, here is the LINQ statement which works well.

```
public static bool IsContiguous(this IEnumerable<DateTime> dates)
{
var startDate = dates.FirstOrDefault();

if (startDate == null)
    return true;

//.All() doesn't provide an indexed overload :(
return dates
    .Select((d, i) => new { Date = d, Index = i })
    .All(d => (d.Date - startDate).Days == d.Index);
}
```

What I would like to now try and achieve is returning the first 'block' of dates that is continuous, for example if these were the dates entered into the system.

```
2019-12-24 
2019-12-25 
2019-12-26 
2020-01-04 
2020-01-05 
2020-01-10
```

How can I have it so that rather than a bool value being returned, that I can have the first and last dates in the first contiguous block returned. The expected outcome would be 24th to 26th. Everything after this would be superfluous.

I'm actually not really sure how to start on this solution, so if anyone has any ideas on where to start or point me to, i would very much appreciate that.

**EDIT:**
Thinking I can somehow use the original DateTime List to then 'remove' dates that are not sequential based on the first date?

```
        List<DateTime> contiguousDates = new List<DateTime>
        {
            new DateTime(2019, 12, 24),
            new DateTime(2019, 12, 25),
            new DateTime(2019, 12, 26),
            new DateTime(2020, 01, 04),
            new DateTime(2020, 01, 05),
            new DateTime(2020, 01, 10),
        };
```

So if the above was the initial List, then could the LINQ query remove records which are not contiguous, leaving the List with only 2019-12-24, 2019-12-25, 2019-12-26?

Comment: You know how to achieve this with integers ? For DateTime you have to use DateTime:AddDays(1) to step from one day to the next. And to Compare, you workonly with DateTime.Date, this is only the Date component without Time.
The rest is the same as you would do with integer.

Comment: Do you want your search always to start at position 0 only ? Cause 01/04-01/05 is also a continous range, a second one.

Comment: have you tried a for each loop? you just have to set a variable or two, for "this is new streak start" once next date = curDate +1, and once you reached the end of the streak get the start you remembered

Comment: @Holger I would like for the first contigous date span to be returned. I would also be curious to know if we can also 'stamp' the 2nd contigous date block for use also. Maybe another column to denote which 'block' it belongs to? If that could happen then basedc on the example dates there would be 3 blocks. The first would have 3 dates, the 2nd with 2, and the last block just the Jan 10th.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static List<DateTime> FindFirstStreak(List<DateTime> dates)
{
    if (dates.Count == 1)
        return dates; // consider using .ToList() here to work on a copy

    var ret = new List<DateTime>();
    for (int i = 0; i < dates.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        var today = dates[i];
        var tom = today.AddDays(1);
        var next = dates[i + 1];

        if (next == tom)
        {
            if (ret.Count == 0) ret.Add(today);
            ret.Add(tom);
        }
        else
        {
            if (ret.Count > 0)
            {
                // check if streak has ended
                if (next != tom)
                    return ret;

                // optional: add ret, to result List<List<DateTime>> 
                // and reset ret = new List<DateTime>(), to get all streaks
            }
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: I would do `return dates` as this means this function returns the same instance that went in only in one circumstance. It'd be better to to `return dates.ToList()`.

Comment: @Enigmativity you think it could cause bugs if one would modify the returned collection after calling the method? ok fair point, although i'm a big fan of reusing objects and not copying them.

Comment: I meant to say "I wouldn't do". Typo sorry, but you got what I meant. I would only ever re-use immutable objects. There is very very little performance gain in re-using objects. Do you have another reason?

Answer (score 0):

Give this a go:

```
List<DateTime> contiguousDates = new List<DateTime>
{
    new DateTime(2019, 12, 24),
    new DateTime(2019, 12, 25),
    new DateTime(2019, 12, 26),
    new DateTime(2020, 01, 04),
    new DateTime(2020, 01, 05),
    new DateTime(2020, 01, 10),
};

var result = 
    contiguousDates
        .Skip(1)
        .Zip(contiguousDates, (x1, x0) => new { x1, x0 })
        .StartWith(new { x1 = contiguousDates.First(), x0 = contiguousDates.First().AddDays(-1.0) })
        .TakeWhile(x => x.x1.Subtract(x.x0).TotalDays == 1.0)
        .Select(x => x.x1)
        .ToList();
```

That produces:

```
2019/12/24 00:00:00 
2019/12/25 00:00:00 
2019/12/26 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `TakeWhile()` in combination with a bit of date arithmetics like this:

```
List<DateTime> dates = new List<DateTime>
{
    new DateTime(2019, 12, 24),
    new DateTime(2019, 12, 25),
    new DateTime(2019, 12, 26),
    new DateTime(2020, 01, 04),
    new DateTime(2020, 01, 05),
    new DateTime(2020, 01, 10),
};

var initial = dates[0];
var contiguous = dates.TakeWhile((date, i) => date == initial.AddDays(i)).ToList();
```

If you want all the continuous blocks contained in the original sequence, you can get a little creative with `GroupBy()` instead:

```
var blocks = dates.Select((date, i) => new {date, i}).GroupBy(x => x.date.AddDays(-x.i))
    .Select(group => group.ToList()).ToList();
```